# Logout Page not working in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a logout page for django.

This is the views.py file:

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('webapp/login.html')
    else:
        result = Hello_World.delay()
        somethingDownByCelery = result.get(timeout=2)
        context = {'somethingDownByCelery': somethingDownByCelery, 'userName': request.user.username}
        return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', context)

def loginUser(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('webapp/index.html')
        else:
            return redirect('webapp/disabled.html')
    else:
        condition = "Invalid Login"
        context = {'condition', condition}
        return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('webapp/index.html')
```

This is the index page after the logout is initiated.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'WebApp/style.css' %}"/>


Hello World, this will call celery!
<html>
    <br>
</html>
{{ somethingDownByCelery }}

<html>
    <br>
    <br>
</html>
Hello! {{ userName }}

<html>
    <br>
    <br>
</html>

<form action="{% url 'WebApp:logout'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> Logout </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What should happen is that the user would logout, and get redirected to the index page, whereas since the user is not logged in, it will redirect the user to a login page.

However, it only shows me: The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object.

This is the project root urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from WebApp import views
from StripCal import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Dashboard_Web.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^webapp/', include('WebApp.urls', namespace="WebApp")),
)
```

This is the app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from WebApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
)
```

Comment: why dont you do: ``return HttpResponseRedirect('webapp/index.html')`` instead of ``return redirect('webapp/index.html')`` ?

Comment: Also why are you posting to log out? You'll get a request even with a `GET`.

Comment: Because if someone makes a pre-fetch, the outcome will be funny

Comment: You're not actually entering the logoutUser view at all, as evidenced by the error message: somehow you're going to django.contrib.auth.logout, which isn't a view. Can you post your urls.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect

def logoutUser(request):
   logout(request)
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/loginpage/')
```

instead of `webapp/index.html`, you should give the URL of your login page like `/loginpage/` inside `HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: Unfortunately, HttpResponseRedirect doesn't work either. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @user1157751 see my update. you should give the URL of loginpage.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I did HttpReponseRedict('/login.html') does not work either.

Comment: @user1157751 it is because you have ``url(r'^login', views.login, name='login')`` and not ``url(r'^login.html', views.login, name='login')``

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your own, use Djangos builtin logout view for this.

```
#urls.py

from django.contrib.auth.views import logout

url(r'^sign-out/$', logout, {'template_name': 'index.html', 'next_page': '/'}, name='sign-out'),
```

[Docs are found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout) and now you can link to this without the use of a form and Django will take care of doing the redirection for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'd rather do it the "raw" way, because I'm new to Django views.

Comment: Yeah, no worries, but why reinvent the wheel on something simple when it's provided for you and when you can put that time to better use learning it on something else related :)

Comment: I've actually tried to use this url, and it works perfectly, but it just seems black magic D:

Comment: Heh, it's the framework. It provides you with the tools you need. To make it seem like less black magic, here's the source https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L64

Comment: Thanks for the source file!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a old post, but no answer addressed what went wrong in the code so here it is.
In the webapp `urls.py` file view must be pointing to logoutUser view and not logout view.
and similarly with the login view

```
from django.contrib import admin
from WebApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login', views.loginUser, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
)
```

Now the url function is taking the intended view method as an argument

Answer (score 0):

First things first.
Your function should look similar to this one:

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/login')
```

To use logout, you have to import logout like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
```

If you are redirecting user on the basis of User.is_authenticated, it would never redirect because if the user is not logged in, an anonymous user it created.
You can do something like ths:

```
def home(request):
if request.user.is_anonymous == True:
    return redirect('/login')
else:
    return render(request,"index.html",{'nav':request.user})
```